# How to update(C.R.U.D) the original slice value in Golang with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, go

I am just getting started learning Golang and PostgreSQL.
I tried to make a simple Todo_List to improve my coding skill.

For now, I try to code the "Update" part in C.R.U.D.
I received and read data from http.Reqeust by using Unmarshal and when I check the console it printed out as well. However, I am struggling with updating this receiving data to an original slice. (In my code, todo)

Could you help me which part is wrong or how to solve it??

Here is my whole code: https://go.dev/play/p/qjW74UVEjpR

I am sorry there are pretty many comments and fmt.Println. I tried to check all conditions what I want...

Comment: it would be good if you add the same code in your question and point out the position where you think the issue is

Answer (score 0):

you should use Updates method. [Link](https://go.dev/play/p/Q2FINQk-uvU)

```
var params = map[string]interface{}{}
if todoDetails.Id != 0 {
    todoDetails.Id = updateTodo.Id
}
if todoDetails.Title != "" {
    //todoDetails.Title = updateTodo.Title
    params["title"] = todoDetails.Title
}
if todoDetails.Description != "" {
    //todoDetails.Description = updateTodo.Description
    params["description"] = todoDetails.Description
}
if todoDetails.Condition != true || false {
    //todoDetails.Condition = updateTodo.Condition
    params["condition"] = todoDetails.Condition
}
err = db.Model(&Todo{}).Where("id = ?",updateTodo.Id).Updates(params).Error
if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    return 
}
```